# In Flutter how to control the width of the column using the pdf lib

Tags: flutter

This is the code which create the table for the pdf. but when the last third column width is too long it need to little longer than the longest text.

```
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pdfLib;
    
pdf.addPage(
      pdfLib.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: customPageFormat,
        build: (context) => [
          pdfLib.TableHelper.fromTextArray(
            cellStyle: pdfLib.TextStyle(font: pdfLib.Font.helvetica(),letterSpacing: .75),            
            headerCount:0,
            data: billdata,
            columnWidths: {
              0: pdfLib.FixedColumnWidth(50.0), 
              1: pdfLib.FixedColumnWidth(50.0),
              3: pdfLib.FixedColumnWidth(50.0), 
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]